# Is there a way I can append a string between two lists

Tags: python, database, list

lets suppose that we have two lists

```
list_one = [1, 2, 3]
list_two = [A, B, C]
```

I want to append "@" to both these lists, the final output should come out as

```
list_final = [1 @ A, 2 @ B, 3 @ C]
```

so basically it takes the first elements from both lists and places a "@" between them and concatenates all the three, suggest a piece of code that can do this

Comment: Use `zip()` to iterate through the lists in parallel, and a list comprehension to create the final list.

Comment: And an f-string like `f"{item_one} @ {item_two}"` to concatenate the pieces.

Comment: Those are all the building blocks. If you're a programmer you should be able to put them together into a working program.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you can use `map` with string formatting to iterate over lists in parallel:

```
list_one = [1, 2, 3]
list_two = ["A", "B", "C"]

result = list(map("{} @ {}".format, list_one, list_two))
# ['1 @ A', '2 @ B', '3 @ C']
```

Here, `"{} @ {}".format` is a function that takes two arguments and returns a string. For example, `"{} @ {}".format(1, "x") == "1 @ x"`. Given a two-argument function and two lists of arguments, we can conveniently compute the list element-wise applications using `map`. For example, `list(map(lambda x, y: x+y, [1, 2, 3], [10, 20, 30])) == [11, 22, 33]`.

Answer (score 0):

if you want final list to consist of smaller parts:

```
list_final=[]
for i in range(len(list_one)):
    list_final.append((list_one[i],"@",list_two[i]))
print(list_final)
```

if you want all elements be unnested:

```
list_final=[]
for i in range(len(list_one)):
    list_final.append(list_one[i])
    list_final.append("@")
    list_final.append(list_two[i])
print(list_final)
```

Answer (score 0):

The comments should have guided you already to the answer. Usage of `zip()` is key here. Then you can opt for a loop or for a list comprehension.

What `zip()` does is to iterate over sequences and pair together the items for each sequence based on their position (first with first, second with second etc.)

Below an example with a for loop and list comprehenstion.

```
list_one = [1, 2, 3]
list_two = ['A', 'B', 'C']
my_list = []
for (item1, item2) in zip(list_one, list_two):
    my_list.append(f"{item1} @  {item2}")
print(my_list)

my_list_conc = [f"{item1} @  {item2}" for item1, item2 in zip(list_one, list_two)]
print(my_list_conc)
```